# Wrong Shapes for Given Matrices in OpenCv 3.1 - Java

Tags: java, c++, opencv, matrix, machine-learning

I have trained the FaceRecognizer all the images are of same size and passed the grayscale image to the predictor. But i face this error

**OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Wrong shapes for given matrices. Was size(src) = (1,150544), size(W) = (37636,5).) in subspaceProject, file /home/********/opencv/modules/core/src/lda.cpp, line 182**

Here is the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        String trainingDir = "res/";
        File root = new File(trainingDir);
        FilenameFilter imgFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                name = name.toLowerCase();
                return name.endsWith(".jpg") || name.endsWith(".pgm") || name.endsWith(".png");
            }
        };

        File[] imageFiles = root.listFiles(imgFilter);
        ArrayList <Mat> images = new ArrayList(imageFiles.length);
        Mat labels = new Mat(imageFiles.length,1,CvType.CV_32SC1);
        int[][] labelsBuffer = new int[imageFiles.length][imageFiles.length];

        int counter =0;
        for(File image: imageFiles){
            Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread(image.getAbsolutePath(),Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
            int label = Integer.parseInt(image.getName().split("\\.")[2]);
            //images.add(label, img);
            images.add(img);
            counter++;
        }
        FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = Face.createEigenFaceRecognizer();
        Mat temp = new Mat();

        faceRecognizer.train(images, labels);
        CascadeClassifier cascadeFaceClassifier = new CascadeClassifier(
                "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
        VideoCapture videoDevice = new VideoCapture();
        videoDevice.open(0);
        int x = 0;
        if (videoDevice.isOpened()) {
            while (true) {      
                Mat frameCapture = new Mat();
                videoDevice.read(frameCapture);
                MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();
                cascadeFaceClassifier.detectMultiScale(frameCapture, faces, 2.0, 5, 0,new Size(),new Size());


                for (Rect rect : faces.toArray()) {
                    Mat resizedCapture = new Mat(frameCapture,rect);
                    Imgproc.cvtColor(resizedCapture, resizedCapture, Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
                    Size imageSize = new Size(194,194);
                    Imgproc.resize(resizedCapture,resizedCapture , imageSize);

                    System.out.println(images.get(0).rows());
                    System.out.println(resizedCapture.rows());
                    System.out.println(images.get(0).cols());
                    System.out.println(resizedCapture.cols());
                    try{
                        x = faceRecognizer.predict_label(resizedCapture);
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    x++;
                    Imgproc.putText(frameCapture, "Face"+x, new Point(rect.x,rect.y-5), 1, 2, new Scalar(0,0,255));
                    Imgproc.rectangle(frameCapture, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),new Scalar(0, 100, 0),3);
                }



                PushImage(ConvertMat2Image(frameCapture));
                //System.out.println(String.format("FACES = %s EYES =  %s detected.", faces.toArray().length,eyes.toArray().length,nose.toArray().length));
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Video Device Not Working");
            return;
        }
    }
    private static BufferedImage ConvertMat2Image(Mat matImage) {


        MatOfByte matOfByte = new MatOfByte();
        Imgcodecs.imencode(".jpg", matImage, matOfByte);
        byte[] byteArray = matOfByte.toArray();
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
            img = ImageIO.read(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return img;
    }

    public static void PencereHazirla() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setSize(700, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public static void PushImage(Image img2) {
        if (frame == null)
            PencereHazirla();
        if (lbl != null)
            frame.remove(lbl);
        icon = new ImageIcon(img2);
        lbl = new JLabel();
        lbl.setIcon(icon);
        frame.add(lbl);
        frame.revalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post the entire code, it can cause no one will read your question.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil Thanks you for your suggestion. But the thing is i think this kind of problem must be posted with whole code. And it's only the code to the problem i am talking about

Comment: @Hasnain you need to create a minimum code example that demonstrates the problem, start by just removing extraneous code over and over until you have something that contains just the code needed to replicate your problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MarkOmo tHANKS you so much i will take care of it next time.

Answer (score 0):

I was  trying Image.cvtColor and converting in to grayscale using Imagecodecs adds 4x.
The solution to this is

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(resizedCapture, resizedCapture, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
```

[Answer Given on opencv community](http://answers.opencv.org/question/149865/wrong-shapes-for-given-matrices-in-opencv-31-java/)